# Passing value in PHP through hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I a crating a university database, want to make edit option in table so that specific record can be edited by user. But every time I am getting syntax error or parse. Here is the link below. Hope someone can help. I think the problem lies here

`echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . </a>;`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Connection error");
mysqli_select_db($con,"lecture7")or die("dbase error");

$sql="select * from students";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border=1>
    <th>RollNo</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>Update</th>";

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))


  {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['RollNo'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['class'];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . </a>;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<br>";


   }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
echo "<a href='www.testpage.php?id=".$row['RollNo']."'>".$row['RollNo']."</a>";
```

And access it by $_GET global variable:-

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

Happy Coding....

Comment: Your code would lead to a syntax error as well.

Comment: Nop. I've edited already.

Comment: Well, back when I commented it was wrong. Not it would work :)

Comment: But now it works fine....

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
<?php
 echo "<a href=\"www.testpage.php?rollno=$row['RollNo']\">$row['RollNo']</a>";
?>
```

then on **testpage.php**

```
<?php

            //check if rool number is set and not empty
    if(isset($_GET['RollNo']) && !empty($_GET['RollNo'])){


        $rollno = intval($_GET['RollNo']);


        //continue with your code
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . </a>;
```

With:

```
echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . '</a>';
```

And it should work. (At least this was a syntax error, haven't looked at the rest).

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . </a>;
```

to:

```
echo '<a href="www.testpage.php">' . $row['RollNo'] . '</a>';
```

Here is how you can optimize to make it readable:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>" .
        "<td>" . $row['RollNo']. "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>" .
        "<td>" . $row['class'] . "</td>" .
        "<td><a href='www.testpage.php'>" . $row['RollNo'] . "</a></td>" . 
        "</tr>";
   }
```